# Windows Phone 8: SharePoint Online Authentication via ADFS

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, authentication, adfs, mobile

I'm trying to develop a Windows Phone app using **[Windows Phone 8.1 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=36818)** and **[Microsoft SharePoint SDK for Windows Phone 8](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=36818)**. I was able to successfully authenticate against a normal SharePoint Online site that uses no ADFS:

```
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        Authenticator at = new Authenticator();
        at.UserName = Login;
        at.Password = password;
        at.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.MicrosoftOnline;
        at.CookieCachingEnabled = true;

        SetAdfsSettings(at);
        //at.FederationPassiveAuthUri =  "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password";

        context.Credentials = at;
        List photos= context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Photos");
```

However, when I'm trying to authenticate against our corporate SharePoint online site that uses ADFS for SSO, I fail to do so. The problem occurs when I am asked to enter Microsoft credentials. As soon as I enter myLogin@company.com I'm redirected to the page that shows 401 error:

[image]

[image]

I have a suspicion that I end up at our corporate ADFS site. I thought I could check the URL with Fiddler and WinPhone Emulator, but during the redirect I'm just stuck at this screen:
[image]

The code I use when trying to connect to the site that used ADFS:

```
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        Authenticator at = new Authenticator();
        at.UserName = Login;
        at.Password = password;
        at.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.MicrosoftOnline;
        at.CookieCachingEnabled = true;

       // SetAdfsSettings(at);
        at.FederationPassiveAuthUri =  "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password";
        at.NavigateBackAfterAuthentication = true;
        at.AllowSmartRouting = true;
        at.PromptOnFailure = true;
        //at.UagServerUrl = new Uri("https://adfs.mycompany.com/adfs/ls/");

        context.Credentials = at;
        List photos= context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Photos");
        UploadDocument(photos, siteUrl, "Photos/", "photo.jpg", photo);
```

I've captured authentication requests/responses when using CSOM and Console application. So I know pretty well where the requests should go. But I have no idea how to force Authenticator class to work correctly.

Here are all requests that happen when I succcessfully authenticate via a Console application:

> 1. POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/GetUserRealm.srf HTTP/1.1
> 2. POST https://adfs.mycompany.com/adfs/services/trust/2005/usernamemixed HTTP/1.1
> 3. POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/rst2.srf HTTP/1.1
> 4. GET https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/idcrl.svc/ HTTP/1.1

So the question is this: How do I use Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Authenticator class (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Phone.Auth.Ui.dll) to work with our corporate ADFS?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft SharePoint SDK for Windows Phone is completely dead. Mobile C# CSOM library does not really work any longer and was not updated for years.